# How to get function arguments' text value in js?

Tags: javascript

I find some code:

```
<a onclick="return dosomething('1234567')"></a>
```

I want to get the "1234567", Is there anyway to get it without Regular expressions ?

The code is in the html on www.xxxxxxxx.com and **I can't change**, the argument in dosomething function is data used as id.I want collect the id information.

So the html might be

```
<a onclick="return dosomething('1')"></a>
<a onclick="return dosomething('2')"></a>
<a onclick="return dosomething('3')"></a>
<a onclick="return dosomething('4')"></a>
```

I want run some js code in **browser's console** to get data like "1","2","3","4"

I have used jquery get the html like

```
$("a")
```

Then I don't know how to get the argument in "dosomething function". It is only a text to me.

Comment: 'Get it' how? When? From where, in what context? In response to what? With JavaScript?

Comment: Please post your entire code.

Comment: If you click the anchor, you'll get it ?

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you're asking. You'll have to do some string parsing or regex to extract that argument. You can get the function text by simply starting with $('a').attr('onclick'), but once you have that, it's simply a string, so you have to do the work of extracting it at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    var txt = $('a[onclick^="return dosomething("]').map(function () {
        return this.getAttribute('onclick').match(/'.*'/)[0];
    }).get().join(",");
    alert(txt);
});
```

**EDIT:** without RegExp

```
$(function () {
    var txt = $('a[onclick^="return dosomething("]').map(function () {
        var attr = this.getAttribute('onclick');
        return attr.substring(attr.indexOf("'"), attr.lastIndexOf("'") + 1);
    }).get().join(",");
    alert(txt);
});
```

Comment: I'm looking up the way without Regular expressions.Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't explain what I need.The Code like ` attr.getFunctionArgs[0]` . Now I think it unreasonable let js has this method. Your code is useful , thanks a lost.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var new_text = "";
    $("a").each(function(){
        var str = $(this).attr("onclick");

        var newtext = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"));
        if(new_text=="")
            new_text += newtext;
        else
            new_text += ","+newtext;            
    });
    alert(new_text);
    console.log("New Text : "+new_text);
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s4a4ghqe/1/)**